# Start Single Container in Python Testcontainers DockerCompose

Tags: python, docker, testcontainers

I have a docker compose file that specifies multiple containers, say `db` and `api`. I would like to start those within a testcontainer in a python application's test setup, using [testcontainers-python](https://testcontainers-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/README.html).
However, I can't just do the following:

```py
with DockerCompose("testdata/docker", "docker-compose.yml") as compose:
    # do something here
    ...
```

That is, because the API I depend on is somewhat unfortunate, in that it requires the DB to be fully set up, by the time it starts; and the DB container does not come initialized. Hence, if I just run the compose (equivalent to `docker-compose up -d`), the API will crash because it finds an un-initialized DB.

What I need to be able to do, is as follows:

1. start the db (`docker-compose up -d db`)
2. run a number of commands to initialize the DB
3. start the db (`docker-compose up -d`)
4. wait for the API to be ready

Now, I can't figure out any way to do this with `DockerCompose()`, and documentation is somewhat limited ([here](https://testcontainers-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/compose/README.html)). Is there a way to do this?

Another option I've been playing around with, is to use `DockerContainer()` instead (documented [here](https://testcontainers-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core/README.html)), with which I seem to be able to start a container at a time.
But this seems extremely cumbersome, as I have to specify all the container configuration in code; I also didn't manage to wait for the container properly, so I even had to implement my own polling mechanism. And finally, I wouldn't know how to get the docker network to do what it should, so the containers can communicate, without compose. All in all, this feels "more low-level than it should be", so I strongly suspect I'm missing something.